# Python String Argument from Batch File

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I have python script test.py:

```
import sys

random_strings = sys.argv[1]

print(random_strings)
```

And a batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p random_strings = "WRITE YOUR WORDS: "
c:
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
python G:\my_file\test.py %random_strings%
pause
conda deactivate
```

My goal is to run this batch file and it will pop up in cmd with question WRITE YOUR WORDS: . Then I will write a random string and it runs in python. The problem is every time I write in cmd WRITE YOUR WORDS: SOME RANDOM WORDS, it will give result IndexError: list index out of range. Did I miss something here?

Comment: To fix your issue you could use, on line `5`, the actual variable which you defined on line `2`, i.e. `%random_strings %`, _(note the space)_, although you should preferably use the correct and recommended syntax for the `set` command instead: `set /p "random_strings=WRITE YOUR WORDS: "`. In addition, you're using the term `random_strings`, but as you're using only `sys.argv[1]`, it should just be `random_string`, in the case of your question that would be `SOME`.

Comment: you're also just going to get the first argument using `sys.argv[1]` unless the string is double quoted. So if you are sticking to this method, use `set /p random_"strings=WRITE YOUR WORDS: "` and then do `python G:\my_file\test.py "%random_strings%"` with the double quotes around `"%random_strings%"`

Comment: In fact, I've just noticed that in your last question, your provided code, and the answer you received, both used that recommended syntax. For that reason, this should be treated as solved in a way which will not be of use to future readers, and you should delete it.